# Do I have to clean the stack when I call the C function "exit" from assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, stack-pointer

I was asked to create a small program in assembly while using C functions. While doing so, I was wondering about something specific.

I know that when working with assembly, wherever I want to call a C function, I must push it's arguments to the stack, and after the function returned I must pop those arguments (or add 4×*x* to `esp`, where *x* represents the number of pushed arguments).

**My question is this:**
When calling the C function `exit` in particular, I must first push an argument for the status. Let's say I want to push 0 to indicate that my program worked without errors.

Knowing that the `exit` function does not return and that I must use it and can't just call the exit system interrupt myself, how can I, in this case, pop that 0 from the stack? Does the `exit` function perform that for me?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to. As `exit()` does not return and the program is terminated, the system will deallocate all memory you used, including the stack.

Note though that the compiler will generate an `add esp, 4` to cleanup the stack because the compiler doesn't know that `exit` will never return.

Comment: Unless your standard library's `exit` function is suitably annotated to inform the optimizer that it does not return. Neither MSVC, GCC, nor ICC emit such a superfluous stack-cleanup instruction. :-)

Comment: Thank you that is what I thought as well but wanted to make sure.

Comment: One thing you can do is emitting an `ud2` instruction right afterwards to underline that the function must not return.